# selenium locate list, the list need click

Tags: list, selenium, locate

```
 <div class="tab-content" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1">
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel">
<div class="image-selection" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0">
<div class="active" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=13469965627809213" data-type="centos" tabindex="-1">
<div class="" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18596926569705582" data-type="coreos" tabindex="-1">
<div class="" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045" data-type="debian" tabindex="-1">
<img data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.0" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACYAAAAmCAMAAACf4xmcAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAH+UExURQAAAM3Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly83Ly...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">
<p data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.1">debian</p>
<ul data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.2">
<li data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.2.0">
<li data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.2.1:$0=106447977267581051">debian6.0.10 64位 基础版</li>
<li data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.2.1:$0=18995325015441454">debian7.8 64位 基础版</li>
<li data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=18906258853045.2.1:$0=1368072207254144">debian7.8 64位 docker版</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=19625720578642721" data-type="opensuse" tabindex="-1">
<div class="" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=16953234329707462" data-type="ubuntu" tabindex="-1">
<div class="" data-reactid=".0.2.1.0.0.0.3.1.$0/=10.0.$0=135222387374229913" data-type="windows" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```

i want locate the image:debian6.0.10 64位 基础版, but i fault...
please help me, thank you so much

Comment: Provide code that failed

Comment: what approach you are using to locate???

Comment: i used  "   driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-type='centos']/ul/li[2]")[0].click()  "  but i fault